# Wireless not working on XP with new Zyxel router

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I just got a new router with build in WiFi. I can connect to it with a Vista based computer, so the wireless part on the router works.

However I cannot get my old Toshiba Satellite laptop (with windows XP) to connect to it, no matter if I use old WPA-PSK or ancient WEP.

When I go connect and put in credentials the dialog stays up for a few minutes then disappears with no message and no connection is established.

Here's the spec of router and wireless card in the XP laptop:

- Wireless card: **[Intel® PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/pro2200bg/)**
- Router: Zyxel P-660-HW-T1 v3

Any help appreciated!

Comment: went back to the old router ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of a solution but ... I parked the new router and went back to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP and WPA are not great buddies,had the same router from my ISP (Telefonica) and the time-outs and disconnected were very common,sometimes i cant even connect to my wireless in the XP O.S, in my case changing the type of WPA worked for me.

Please upgrade your system to another O.S like Windows 7-8.1 or any Linux distro if you can.

Edit: I just remember that router had a bug in the firmware with the XP O.S, look for the latest firmware.